# It looks like concrete, but does concrete overlay feel like concrete?

Tags: concrete, countertops

Disclaimer:  This is not a spam post, Ed.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEazDBRc2GY), a "concrete" countertop is built using mostly plywood with a concrete overlay.

It looks okay, but I'm wondering if it actually feels like concrete.  If you pound your fist on the counter, will it thud like wood?

Has anyone here done this?

Comment: Might sound like wood, but they are using very thick wood and be very solid.  It should hurt your fist the same as concrete.  As they say, using real concrete would be very heavy on a small section of floor, probably requiring extra floor supports.

Comment: You can watch the video to me this was more like a spam on the products as the process is laid out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because all the info is in the video and it is more like spam.

Comment: If the wood has any bend or give whatsoever you would see cracks in the concrete veneer. Ditto for humidity. As soon as the wood expands or contracts the whole project will go to shite.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  You can see things however you want.  This was not a spam post.  Nowhere in the video does he talk about the feel of the counter after completion and he does not demonstrate in any way how it sounds when utilized.

Comment: While I get that this is a legit question, I see @Ed's point. It would be better if you could flesh out the details in the question in your own words, instead of relying on the video to provide the heavy lifting. We really shouldn't have to go watch a video at all, just to understand and respond usefully to the question. Please [edit the question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/229221/edit) so that everything anyone would need to answer it is in the question itself.

Comment: We have a composite worktop in our kitchen which is plywood and engineered stone on top - it's not concrete though, but it sounds (when knocking on it) closer to the laminated wooden worktop we have than a true stone surface. It _feels_ closer to the stone surface than the laminated one though, so it has a bit of both properties.